# Testing Touch Events in Non-Touch-Development Environmet

Tags: javafx

I develop a JavaFX application, which will be used on a system with touchscreen.

My development machine does not have a touchscreen. In this environment the app looks like a desktop application.

Is it possible to (manually) test touch based behaviour with JavaFX on a non-touch based device?

Is there some kind of emulator for JavaFX Applications which emulates touch events. (Similiar to android emulator for android apps?)

Answer (score 2):

You can construct a [touch event with a constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/input/TouchEvent.html), then [fire the event on a stage](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Window.html#fireEvent-javafx.event.Event-).  You can [add a filter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Window.html#addEventFilter-javafx.event.EventType-javafx.event.EventHandler-) on your stage for mouse events, consume them and fire a touch event in their stead.  For example:

```
stage.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, mouseEvent -> {
    mouseEvent.consume();
    Event touchEvent = new TouchEvent(lotsaparameters...);
    stage.fireEvent(touchEvent);
});
```

Comment: If you use cordinates outside the stage will there be an error or does it work?

Comment: This is an event filter on the stage.  It will filter events which are routed to the stage.  Co-ordinates outside the stage won't be routed to the stage.  If you press a mouse outside of the stage, as expected, there will be no error, because no error has occurred; nothing will happen because the event filter will not be triggered.

Comment: I would like whatever is outside the stage to be clicked, but that does not seem to happen

Comment: Of course it doesn't.  That isn't what this question asked or what this answer provides.  If you have a new question, please ask it as a new question.

Comment: Remember that when you simulate the events programtically lke that, it is not the same as someone would touch that x,y position on the screen. If some controls mistakenly would be placed over eachother - it does not help at all to do it this way. As far as I can tell there is no thing such as awt.robot for touch events - as I am also looking to test touch events - I think there is a way to do this and that solution I think is related to being able to fire events outside the stage (without any target most prefferably).

Comment: Check DVargas post (the above part) he explains this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40041625/how-to-fire-mouse-event-programmatically-in-javafx/40042513#comment79900468_40042513

Answer (score 0):

Code that calls the event.source with a touch event

```
        button.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
            TextField tf = (TextField) event.getSource();
            Stage stage = (Stage) tf.getScene().getWindow();
            double sceX = event.getSceneX();
            double sceY = event.getSceneY();
            double scrX = event.getScreenX();
            double scrY = event.getScreenY();
            TouchPoint tp = new TouchPoint(1, TouchPoint.State.PRESSED, sceX, sceY, scrX, scrY, (EventTarget) event.getSource(), null);                
            ArrayList<TouchPoint> tpa = new ArrayList<>();
            tpa.add(tp);
            tf.fireEvent(new TouchEvent(TouchEvent.TOUCH_PRESSED, 
                    tp,
                    tpa,
                    1,
                    false, 
                    false, 
                    false, 
                    false)
            );
            event.consume();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Can you do this without specifying onto which node?