# How to fire mouse event programmatically in JavaFX?

Tags: java, events, javafx

The following code show two panels, yellow and blue, where blue is a child of yellow.

If I click into the center of blue panel, mouse event is handled with both panels.

How to simulate the same behavior programmatically?

In the `Fire event` button I tried to do this, but failed: generated event appeared to handled only by yellow pane.

Is it possible to post event so that it processed by all children as if it happen with "native" events?

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.Event;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Point2D;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseButton;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class FireMouseEventProgrammatically extends Application {

   @Override
   public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

      BorderPane root = new BorderPane();




      AnchorPane yellowPane = new AnchorPane();
      yellowPane.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.YELLOW, CornerRadii.EMPTY, Insets.EMPTY)));
      yellowPane.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
         @Override
         public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
            System.out.print("yellowPane clicked ");
            printMouseEvent(event);
            System.out.println("");
         }
      });

      root.setCenter(yellowPane);


      Pane bluePane = new Pane();
      bluePane.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.BLUE, CornerRadii.EMPTY, Insets.EMPTY)));
      bluePane.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
         @Override
         public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
            System.out.print("bluePane clicked ");
            printMouseEvent(event);
            System.out.println("");
         }
      });

      AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(bluePane, 200.);
      AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(bluePane, 200.);
      AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(bluePane, 200.);
      AnchorPane.setBottomAnchor(bluePane, 200.);


      yellowPane.getChildren().add(bluePane);




      FlowPane buttonPane = new FlowPane();
      buttonPane.setHgap(5);
      buttonPane.setPadding(new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5));

      root.setBottom(buttonPane);



      Button fireEventButton = new Button();
      fireEventButton.setText("Fire event");
      fireEventButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
         @Override
         public void handle(ActionEvent event) {

            double blueX = bluePane.getWidth()/2;
            double blueY = bluePane.getHeight()/2;

            Point2D screenCoords = bluePane.localToScreen(blueX, blueY);
            Point2D sceneCoords = bluePane.localToScene(blueX, blueY);

            Event.fireEvent(yellowPane, new MouseEvent(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED,
               sceneCoords.getX(), sceneCoords.getY(), screenCoords.getX(), screenCoords.getY(), MouseButton.PRIMARY, 1,
               true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, null));

         }
      });

      buttonPane.getChildren().add(fireEventButton);


      Scene scene = new Scene(root, 800, 600);
      primaryStage.setScene(scene);
      primaryStage.show();

   }

   private void printMouseEvent(MouseEvent event) {
      System.out.print(String.format("x = %f, y = %f, xScreen = %f, yScreen = %f", event.getX(), event.getY(), event.getScreenX(), event.getScreenY()));
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      FireMouseEventProgrammatically.launch(args);
   }

}
```

**UPDATE**

I can't mention child node explicitly, because in general case it can be numerous number of children.

How would I know which one to target?

I would like to pass coordinates and let system determine targets automatically.

Comment: Isn't that somewhat related to [the question you've asked yesterday](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40023260/3429133)?

Answer (score 9):

The difference between the actual (phisycal) clicking and your programmatic clicking is, that in the first case the original event target is `bluePane` (as it is the "uppermost" `Node` visually), in the latter case the target is `yellowPane`.

So, when the route construction occurs (please refer to the [Event Delivery Process section](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/events/processing.htm)) in the first case the route will be `root` -> `yellowPane` -> `bluePane`, and in the second case it will be only  `root` -> `yellowPane`, hence the `bluePane` is untouched by the event.

Based on this you can target the `bluePane`:

```
Event.fireEvent(bluePane, new MouseEvent(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED,
   sceneCoords.getX(), sceneCoords.getY(), screenCoords.getX(), screenCoords.getY(), MouseButton.PRIMARY, 1,
   true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, null));
```

Or you can use a `Robot` for example to generate the click:

```
try {
    robot = new java.awt.Robot();

    robot.mouseMove((int)screenCoords.getX(), (int)screenCoords.getY());
    robot.mousePress(16);
    robot.mouseRelease(16);
    robot.mouseMove((int) originalLocation.getX(), (int)originalLocation.getY());
} catch (AWTException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

---

**Update 1:**

If you want to stick with the JavaFX way, the question is now **how to determine the "uppermost" `Node` on a position**.

This is one thing that is not possible in a clean way. There is already a [feature request](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8091684) about this.

I have found this on helper method on [fxexperience](http://fxexperience.com/2016/01/node-picking-in-javafx/) that can be used to determinte the `Node` on a certain position:

```
public static Node pick(Node node, double sceneX, double sceneY) {
    Point2D p = node.sceneToLocal(sceneX, sceneY, true /* rootScene */);

    // check if the given node has the point inside it, or else we drop out
    if (!node.contains(p)) return null;

    // at this point we know that _at least_ the given node is a valid
    // answer to the given point, so we will return that if we don't find
    // a better child option
    if (node instanceof Parent) {
        // we iterate through all children in reverse order, and stop when we find a match.
        // We do this as we know the elements at the end of the list have a higher
        // z-order, and are therefore the better match, compared to children that
        // might also intersect (but that would be underneath the element).
        Node bestMatchingChild = null;
        List<Node> children = ((Parent)node).getChildrenUnmodifiable();
        for (int i = children.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            Node child = children.get(i);
            p = child.sceneToLocal(sceneX, sceneY, true /* rootScene */);
            if (child.isVisible() && !child.isMouseTransparent() && child.contains(p)) {
                bestMatchingChild = child;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (bestMatchingChild != null) {
            return pick(bestMatchingChild, sceneX, sceneY);
        }
    }

    return node;
}
```

that you can use like:

```
Node pick = pick(root, sceneCoords.getX(), sceneCoords.getY());
Event.fireEvent(pick, new MouseEvent(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED,
   sceneCoords.getX(), sceneCoords.getY(), screenCoords.getX(), screenCoords.getY(), MouseButton.PRIMARY, 1,
   true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, null));
```

---

**Update2:**

You can also use the **deprecated method** `Node.impl_pickNode(PickRay pickRay, PickResultChooser result)` to get the intersected `Node` on a scene position:

```
PickRay pickRay = new PickRay((int) sceneCoords.getX(), (int) sceneCoords.getY(), 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
PickResultChooser pickResultChooser = new PickResultChooser();
root.impl_pickNode(pickRay,  pickResultChooser);
Node intersectedNode = pickResultChooser.getIntersectedNode();
```

You can use also this `Node` as target similarly.

Comment: I only get the parameters `Event.fireEvent(EventTarget eventTarget, Event event);`. I recently used the other set of parameters for the javaFX.event.Event like in this answer. Any idea what happened? Why I cannot use `Event.fireEvent(EventType<? extends MouseEvent> eventType, double x, double y`...

Comment: `Event.fireEvent` takes two arguments: first one is an `EventTarget` (`pick`, which is a `Node` which implements `EventTarget`), second one is an `Event` (which is `new MouseEvent(...)`).

Comment: Ah, I mixed up the `new MouseEvent(...)` contructor parameters as the being the parameters of the `Event.fireEvent()` method. Thank you.

Comment: Can I set the screen as the eventtarget somehow? I would like to fire an event without having to specify the node. I do not wish to use `awt.Robot` beacuse I need to do testing with touch aswell.

Comment: I fear that does not work with JavaFX events unfortunately. For that the best I could propose is the robot.

Comment: What is the `screenCoords` parameters?

Comment: May I kindly ask any of you to explain what "firing an event" means (what this method `fireEvent` achieves? I looked the [documentation of the method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/event/Event.html#fireEvent-javafx.event.EventTarget-javafx.event.Event-) but I didn't understand what the targetEvent does. I would appreciate any insight!

Answer (score 3):

The location of your MouseEvent is within both blue and yellow panes (blue one is inside yellow). If you do:

```
Event.fireEvent(bluePane, new MouseEvent(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED,
               sceneCoords.getX(), sceneCoords.getY(), screenCoords.getX(), screenCoords.getY(), MouseButton.PRIMARY, 1,
               true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, null));
```

It will work as You expected.

JavaFX could not figure out what component was clicked base on location of a mouse event. You have to explicitly pass the target of the event. In that case it would be bluePane.

More information you can find here:
https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/events/processing.htm

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you want to get the children of the yellowPane, and fire each of their events.

I accomplished this like so

Where `ObservableList<Node> nodes` is the result of `yellowPane.getChildren()`

```
private void clickOnMe(ObservableList<Node> nodes){
        for(Node n : nodes){
            n.fireEvent(new MouseEvent(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED,
                    n.getLayoutX(), n.getLayoutY(), n.getLayoutX(), n.getLayoutY(), MouseButton.PRIMARY, 1,
                    true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, null));
        }
    }
```

This will grab every child of `yellowPane`, which you said could be many, and fire each of their events. Hope this is what you wanted.