# LineChart - Can I zoom in/out and pan from the code?

Tags: javafx, charts, linechart

I'm using JfxUtils and LineChart. In some situations I want to give commands like zoom in/out and panning. Do any of you know a way to achieve this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16680295/javafx-correct-scaling

Comment: @Sedrick Nope, this is not what I ask. I'm using Linechart which already has a zoom and pan options, I just want to do it from the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I did this [How to fire mouse event programmatically in JavaFX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40041625/how-to-fire-mouse-event-programmatically-in-javafx) and made the mouse event act like zoom in/out and pan.