# Transparent JavaFX stage capture scrolling events if there is another window behind

Tags: java, javafx, openjfx

Mouse events and scroll events behave in different ways

[image: diagram]

Mouse Events:

1. The event is captured by mainStage
2. The event is captured by **mainStage**
3. The event is not captured

Scroll Events:

1. The event is captured by mainStage
2. The event is captured by **secondStage**
3. The event is not captured

Is there any way that transparent secondStage does not capture scroll events?

My code:

```java
Pane mainPane = new Pane(new Label("Main Stage"));
mainPane.setPrefSize(300, 300);
mainStage.setScene(new Scene(mainPane));

Stage secondStage = new Stage();
Pane secondPane = new Pane(new Label("Second Stage"));
secondPane.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.TRANSPARENT, CornerRadii.EMPTY, Insets.EMPTY)));
secondPane.setBorder(new Border(
    new BorderStroke(Color.BLACK, BorderStrokeStyle.SOLID, CornerRadii.EMPTY, new BorderWidths(2))));
secondPane.setPrefSize(300, 300);
secondStage.setScene(new Scene(secondPane, Color.TRANSPARENT));
secondStage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);

mainStage.getScene().setOnScroll(event -> System.out.println("Scroll in main stage"));
secondStage.getScene().setOnScroll(event -> System.out.println("Scroll in second stage"));
mainStage.getScene().setOnMouseClicked(event -> System.out.println("Click in main stage"));
secondStage.getScene().setOnMouseClicked(event -> System.out.println("Click in second stage"));

mainStage.show();
secondStage.show();
```

Java version: 1.8.0_201 (64 bits), Windows 10

edit:
The example is a simplification with only two windows. Fire the event programmatically implies discovering which stage is immediately lower and that is another problem in itself.

Comment: Have you tried [`setMouseTransparent`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Node.html#setMouseTransparent(boolean))? Not entirely sure how it would work out with transparent windows though.

Comment: @Avi It behaves exactly the same when change the mouse transparent property in the panels

Comment: :( That's unfortunate. I'll probably be unable to help because I myself am fiddling around with JFoenix's JFXTextArea to get it to work

Comment: @Avi I am very surprised that the event can be propagated to other windows but not to windows of the same application, it may be a bug. Thank you anyway

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but how do you generate a _scroll event_ using the sample code that you posted?

Comment: @Abra You can launch the event by turning the mouse wheel over the window

Comment: It may be a bug. It may be intentional. Why not merely pass the scroll event captured by the transparent stage to the non-transparent stage?

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Abra. Manually launching the event with `Event.fireEvent()` works, but my application has multiple stages and first I would have to find out which one is just below, and that implies another problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be a great coincidence, that we also came with the same solution of transparent window because of not having the feature of managing z-index of stages. And We encountered the exact same issue as yours. ie, scroll events not propagating to underlying Stages. We used the below approach, not sure whether this can help you:

Firstly, We constructed a Singleton class that keeps a reference of Node that is currently hovered on.

Then, when we create any normal stage, we include the below handlers to the scene of that new stage. The key thing here is that, the mouse events are still able to pass through the transparent stage to the underlying window, keep track of node which sits under the mouse.

```
scene.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_EXITED_TARGET, e -> {
    hoverNode.set(null);
});
scene.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVED, e -> {
    hoverNode.set(e.getTarget());
});
```

In the scene of the transparent window, we included the below handlers to delegate the scroll events to the underlying node.

```
scene.addEventFilter(ScrollEvent.SCROLL, e -> {
    if (hoverNode.get() != null) {
        Event.fireEvent(hoverNode.get(), e);
    }
});
scene.addEventHandler(ScrollEvent.SCROLL, e -> {
    if (hoverNode.get() != null) {
        Event.fireEvent(hoverNode.get(), e);
    }
});
```

I am pretty sure this is not the most desired way. But this addressed our issue. :)

Below is the quick demo code of what I mean.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.DoubleProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleDoubleProperty;
import javafx.event.Event;
import javafx.event.EventTarget;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Rectangle2D;
import javafx.scene.Cursor;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.input.ScrollEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Screen;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.StageStyle;

import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class ScrollThroughTransparentStage_Demo extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        stage.setTitle("Main Window");
        VBox root = new VBox(buildScrollPane());
        root.setStyle("-fx-background-color:#888888;");
        root.setSpacing(10);
        root.setPadding(new Insets(10));

        Button normalStageBtn = new Button("Normal Stage");
        normalStageBtn.setOnAction(e -> {
            Stage normalStage = new Stage();
            normalStage.initOwner(stage);
            Scene normalScene = new Scene(buildScrollPane(), 300, 300);
            addHandlers(normalScene);
            normalStage.setScene(normalScene);
            normalStage.show();
        });

        CheckBox allowScrollThrough = new CheckBox("Allow scroll through transparency");
        allowScrollThrough.setSelected(true);

        HBox buttons = new HBox(normalStageBtn);
        buttons.setSpacing(20);
        root.getChildren().addAll(allowScrollThrough,buttons);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 600);
        addHandlers(scene);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

        /* Transparent Stage */
        Stage transparentStage = new Stage();
        transparentStage.initOwner(stage);
        transparentStage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
        Pane mainRoot = new Pane();
        Pane transparentRoot = new Pane(mainRoot);
        transparentRoot.setStyle("-fx-background-color:transparent;");
        Scene transparentScene = new Scene(transparentRoot, Color.TRANSPARENT);
        transparentStage.setScene(transparentScene);
        transparentScene.addEventFilter(ScrollEvent.SCROLL, e -> {
            if (allowScrollThrough.isSelected() && HoverNodeSingleton.getInstance().getHoverNode() != null) {
                Event.fireEvent(HoverNodeSingleton.getInstance().getHoverNode(), e);
            }
        });
        transparentScene.addEventHandler(ScrollEvent.SCROLL, e -> {
            if (allowScrollThrough.isSelected() && HoverNodeSingleton.getInstance().getHoverNode() != null) {
                Event.fireEvent(HoverNodeSingleton.getInstance().getHoverNode(), e);
            }
        });
        determineStageSize(transparentStage, mainRoot);
        transparentStage.show();

        Button transparentStageBtn = new Button("Transparent Stage");
        transparentStageBtn.setOnAction(e -> {
            MiniStage miniStage = new MiniStage(mainRoot);
            ScrollPane scrollPane = buildScrollPane();
            scrollPane.setPrefSize(300, 300);
            miniStage.setContent(scrollPane);
            miniStage.show();
        });
        buttons.getChildren().add(transparentStageBtn);
    }

    private static void determineStageSize(Stage stage, Node root) {
        DoubleProperty width = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
        DoubleProperty height = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
        DoubleProperty shift = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
        Screen.getScreens().forEach(screen -> {
            Rectangle2D bounds = screen.getVisualBounds();
            width.set(width.get() + bounds.getWidth());

            if (bounds.getHeight() > height.get()) {
                height.set(bounds.getHeight());
            }
            if (bounds.getMinX() < shift.get()) {
                shift.set(bounds.getMinX());
            }
        });
        stage.setX(shift.get());
        stage.setY(0);
        stage.setWidth(width.get());
        stage.setHeight(height.get());
        root.setTranslateX(-1 * shift.get());
    }

    private void addHandlers(Scene scene) {
        scene.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_EXITED_TARGET, e -> {
            HoverNodeSingleton.getInstance().setHoverNode(null);
        });
        scene.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVED, e -> {
            HoverNodeSingleton.getInstance().setHoverNode(e.getTarget());
        });
    }

    private ScrollPane buildScrollPane() {
        VBox vb = new VBox();
        vb.setSpacing(10);
        vb.setPadding(new Insets(15));
        IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 100).forEach(i -> vb.getChildren().add(new Label(i + "")));
        ScrollPane scrollPane = new ScrollPane(vb);
        return scrollPane;
    }

    class MiniStage extends Group {
        private Pane parent;
        double sceneX, sceneY, layoutX, layoutY;
        protected BorderPane windowPane;
        private BorderPane windowTitleBar;
        private Label labelTitle;
        private Button buttonClose;

        public MiniStage(Pane parent) {
            this.parent = parent;
            buildRootNode();
            getChildren().add(windowPane);
            addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, e -> toFront());
        }

        @Override
        public void toFront() {
            parent.getChildren().remove(this);
            parent.getChildren().add(this);
        }

        public void setContent(Node content) {
            // Computing the bounds of the content before rendering
            Group grp = new Group(content);
            new Scene(grp);
            grp.applyCss();
            grp.requestLayout();
            double width = grp.getLayoutBounds().getWidth();
            double height = grp.getLayoutBounds().getHeight() + 30; // 30 title bar height
            grp.getChildren().clear();

            windowPane.setCenter(content);
            // Centering the stage
            Rectangle2D screenBounds = Screen.getPrimary().getBounds();
            setX(screenBounds.getWidth() / 2 - width / 2);
            setY(screenBounds.getHeight() / 2 - height / 2);
        }

        public Node getContent() {
            return windowPane.getCenter();
        }

        public void setX(double x) {
            setLayoutX(x);
        }

        public void setY(double y) {
            setLayoutY(y);
        }

        public void show() {
            if (!parent.getChildren().contains(this)) {
                parent.getChildren().add(this);
            }
        }

        public void hide() {
            parent.getChildren().remove(this);
        }

        private void buildRootNode() {
            windowPane = new BorderPane();
            windowPane.setStyle("-fx-border-width:2px;-fx-border-color:#444444;");
            labelTitle = new Label("Mini Stage");
            labelTitle.setStyle("-fx-font-weight:bold;");
            labelTitle.setMaxHeight(Double.MAX_VALUE);
            buttonClose = new Button("X");
            buttonClose.setFocusTraversable(false);
            buttonClose.setStyle("-fx-background-color:red;-fx-background-radius:0;-fx-background-insets:0;");
            buttonClose.setOnMouseClicked(evt -> hide());

            windowTitleBar = new BorderPane();
            windowTitleBar.setStyle("-fx-border-width: 0 0 2px 0;-fx-border-color:#444444;-fx-background-color:#BBBBBB");
            windowTitleBar.setLeft(labelTitle);
            windowTitleBar.setRight(buttonClose);
            windowTitleBar.setPadding(new Insets(0, 0, 0, 10));
            windowTitleBar.getStyleClass().add("nonfocus-title-bar");
            windowPane.setTop(windowTitleBar);
            assignTitleBarEvents();
        }

        private void assignTitleBarEvents() {
            windowTitleBar.setOnMousePressed(this::recordWindowLocation);
            windowTitleBar.setOnMouseDragged(this::moveWindow);
            windowTitleBar.setOnMouseReleased(this::resetMousePointer);
        }

        private final void recordWindowLocation(final MouseEvent event) {
            sceneX = event.getSceneX();
            sceneY = event.getSceneY();
            layoutX = getLayoutX();
            layoutY = getLayoutY();
            getScene().setCursor(Cursor.MOVE);
        }

        private final void resetMousePointer(final MouseEvent event) {
            // Updating the new layout positions
            setLayoutX(layoutX + getTranslateX());
            setLayoutY(layoutY + getTranslateY());

            // Resetting the translate positions
            setTranslateX(0);
            setTranslateY(0);
            getScene().setCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT);
        }

        private final void moveWindow(final MouseEvent event) {
            double offsetX = event.getSceneX() - sceneX;
            double offsetY = event.getSceneY() - sceneY;
            setTranslateX(offsetX);
            setTranslateY(offsetY);
            event.consume();
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Singleton class.
 */
class HoverNodeSingleton {
    private static HoverNodeSingleton INSTANCE = new HoverNodeSingleton();
    private EventTarget hoverNode;

    private HoverNodeSingleton() {
    }

    public static HoverNodeSingleton getInstance() {
        return INSTANCE;
    }

    public EventTarget getHoverNode() {
        return hoverNode;
    }

    public void setHoverNode(EventTarget hoverNode) {
        this.hoverNode = hoverNode;
    }
}
```

Comment: We were thinking of an workaround and this solution solves the problem and is probably the option we choose. Thank you for the detailed answer.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know that's right or not, but you can bind properties:

```
secondStage.getScene().onScrollProperty().bind(mainStage.getScene().onScrollProperty());
```

Comment: I don't think this code is related to the question at all
your are binding the scroll property of the second page to the first page so it will run the same listener if you scroll either the first or the second

Comment: As @AhmedEmad says, this code is not related to the question I ask

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom event dispatcher that will ignore events you don't want:

```
public class CustomEventDispatcher extends BasicEventDispatcher {
    @Override
    public Event dispatchEvent(Event event, EventDispatchChain tail) {
        if(event instanceof ScrollEvent) {
            return null;
        } else {
            return super.dispatchEvent(event, tail);
        }
    }
}
```

Then set that on your stage:

```
secondStage.setEventDispatcher(new CustomEventDispatcher());
```

Comment: The result is still unexpected, now in case 2, nobody captures the scroll events, but my intention is to behave the same as the mouse events. Thanks for the proposal

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how this works in the context of stages but for simple shapes it makes a difference whether you set the fill color to `Color.TRANSPARENT` or just `null`. Using any `Color` catches events, whereas `null` does not.

Comment: using `secondPane.getScene().setFill(null)` or `new BackgroundFill(null, CornerRadii.EMPTY, Insets.EMPTY)` behaves exactly the same in this case

Answer (score 0):

You can do so by ignoring the event on the second stage using event dispatcher using this answer by @Slaw you can understand everything about `EventDispatcher`
https://stackoverflow.com/a/51015783/5303683

Then you can fire your own event using this answer by DVarga
https://stackoverflow.com/a/40042513/5303683
Sorry I don't have time to try and make a full example of it

Comment: What I intend is that the event is not captured, as is the case with mouse events. Capture the event in secondStage and launch it in mainStage programmatically as proposed by @Abra if it solves the simplified example that I present, but not a real case with more than two windows, since I should discover which window is just behind, and that is another problem in itself.

Comment: can I ask what is the reason behind what you want ?

Comment: Sure @AhmedEmad . Currently we have an application with multiple widgets that you can position on the screen, and each of them is a stage. JavaFX does not allow modifying the Z axis of the windows, so we are trying to paint all the widgets on a single transparent stage, a solution that satisfies us except for the problem I explain in this query. We are also observing that a single window improves memory consumption and performance, which pushes us to solve this problem